# Can I use a 12-2 romex 20 amp circuit to feed a local disconnect with a 10-2 weather proof pigtail to a mini split unit?

Tags: electrical

I have an existing 20 amp circuit I would like to use to feed my 115 volt mini split unit. Can I feed an exterior local disconnect with 12-2 wire and then use a 10-2 prewired exterior grade connector to the unit?

Comment: Barring some different detail about the amperage, which would invalidate your 12Ga wire and your 20A circuit, if the unit needed more than that, it's pretty much the same question. I guess we've moved to "one vote close" while I wasn't looking.

Comment: @Ecnerwal people with high reputation may have 1-vote effects, depending on (algorithm stuff here).  But I agree with the dup, this has been asked (not well though).

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica It's not reputation-based; Ecnerwal has a gold tag badge in the [tag:electrical] tag (at least 1000 score (read: upvotes) on answers to questions w/ that tag, across >= 200 non-Community Wiki answers). That means any time Ecnerwal closes a question with that tag as a duplicate of another question, it'll be a unilateral/instant closure w/ no other users needed. Only exception is if Ecnerwal were the one to add the [electrical] tag (to prevent abuse).